# Using Polly for a retry attempt from an async function

Tags: c#, async-await, polly

I'm trying to retry a failed operation 3 times.

I'm using Polly for a retry operation.

I want to get the exception in case the retry operation fails and retry again 2 times and so on.

```
return await Policy
    .Handle<CustomException>()
    .RetryAsync(3, onRetryAsync: async (exception, retryCount, context) =>
    {
        return await runner.run(params);
    });
```

The function should return

```
Task<IReadOnlyCollection<string>>
```

I'm getting the following error:

> async lambda expression converted to a task returning delegate cannot
> return a value

Answer (score 37):

I think it is unusual to run your logic in the retry policy - unless I misunderstand your question. More typically you execute the policy by calling a method that runs your logic.

Something like this:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var polly = Policy
        .Handle<Exception>()           
        .RetryAsync(3, (exception, retryCount, context) => Console.WriteLine($"try: {retryCount}, Exception: {exception.Message}"));

    var result = await polly.ExecuteAsync(async () => await DoSomething());
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

int count = 0;

public async Task<string> DoSomething()
{
    if (count < 3)
    {
        count++;
        throw new Exception("boom");
    }
        
    return await Task.FromResult("foo");
}
```

> output

```
try: 1, Exception: boom
try: 2, Exception: boom
try: 3, Exception: boom
foo
```

Comment: I think you got my question pretty much. Just to make sure I got it.
If the exception would be thrown, DoSomething would run again and if not it will return the result but will not run again?

Comment: Correct, `result` will contain whatever your method returns. If it failed too many times it would just act like it threw an exception normally.

Comment: ok. 2 questions to validate: 1. So if there will be no exception, the same one which failed and no passed won't run again even if we didn't complete the number of retries? 2. Is there a way that polly can pass the exception to DoSomething?

Comment: correct typo for question 1 "So if there will be no exception, the same one which failed and NOW passes won't run again even if we didn't complete the number of retries

Comment: I'm not sure I understand question #1 - that form of Retry policy will try up to 3 times if it needs to. It will not retry at all if no exception that it handles is thrown. #2 - you don't need the exception passed to `DoSomething` because that is where the exception is coming from. You can just use normal `try/catch`.

Comment: Thank you for question 1.
about question 2: I do need the exception because I have data inside that I need to use for the next retry

Comment: In the retry delegate you can set or call something that sets a variable that is accessible by (in this example) `DoSomething`. You could write logic based on it.

Comment: There are overloads of the Retry policy in which the `onRetry` delegate is passed `Polly.Context`. And there are overloads of `ExecuteAsync(...)` where the delegate executed can be passed `Polly.Context` as an input parameter. Thus, you can share data by storing it in the dictionary on `Polly.Context`. See https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Keys-And-Context-Data#using-context-for-custom-data ; http://www.thepollyproject.org/2017/05/04/putting-the-context-into-polly/ . Sharing data via `Polly.Context` avoids sharing a local variable; useful if policy defn is in a different scope from use.

Answer (score 0):

Even though [Crowcoder's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59456926/13268855) provides a working code, it does not really explain too much IMHO.

#### Policy definition and execution

Polly was designed in a way that you define a policy first **then** you execute it. Most of the times these two steps are separated in time and space but there are occasions when you just want to do it right away.

```
var result = Policy
        .Handle<Exception>()           
        .RetryAsync(...)
        .ExecuteAsync(...);
```

I understand that many people got confused with these method chaining (two `XYZAsync` methods). This is mainly because of the absence of the `Build` method call. In the V7 (and prior) API you don't have an explicit *I'm done with the policy definition, now I'm ready to execute it*.

In the V8 API you have to explicitly call the `Build` on the `ResiliencePipelineBuilder` to get a `ResiliencePipeline` which can be executed.

#### `onRetry{Async}`

Polly was designed in a way to allow the library consumers to provide callbacks to react on certain actions. In the old .NET world these would be *events* but with the newer directions these are callbacks.

In other words Polly policies implement the [template method design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). Each policy defines a set of statements that needs to be executed in a given order and provides customization points (in the design pattern they are called **steps**). In the original pattern the steps could be defined/overridden via inheritance. In case of Polly this is done via callback.

The `onRetry{Async}` callback is called

- if a given attempt is failed and a new retry should be triggered (for example an exception thrown which is handled by the policy and the policy did not exceed the maximum retry count)
- but before the sleep duration (if any)

If you define your retry policy with `Retry{Async}` then there is no delay between the retry attempts. If you use `WaitAndRetry{Async}` then you can instruct Polly to take a rest before kicking off a new attempt.

My main point here is that `onRetry{Async}` is a notification hook. So, normally you don't want to execute any business logic here rather just propagate the notification to a persistence storage for tracing.

#### `onRetryAsync` overloads

One of the biggest criticism against Polly V7: there were way too many overloads. Just look at this file: [`AsyncRetrySyntax`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/785c482db4fed149ad5df9c7104f81354f4d6c9c/src/Polly/Retry/AsyncRetrySyntax.cs). It contains almost 20 overloads

```
public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, int retryCount, Func<int, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider)

public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, int retryCount, Func<int, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider, Action<Exception, TimeSpan> onRetry)

public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, int retryCount, Func<int, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider, Func<Exception, TimeSpan, Task> onRetryAsync)

public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, int retryCount,
    Func<int, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider, Action<Exception, TimeSpan, Context> onRetry)

public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, int retryCount,
    Func<int, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider, Func<Exception, TimeSpan, Context, Task> onRetryAsync)

public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, int retryCount, Func<int, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider, Action<Exception, TimeSpan, int, Context> onRetry)

public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, int retryCount,
    Func<int, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider, Func<Exception, TimeSpan, int, Context, Task> onRetryAsync)

public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, int retryCount,
    Func<int, Context, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider, Action<Exception, TimeSpan, Context> onRetry)

public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, int retryCount,
    Func<int, Context, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider, Func<Exception, TimeSpan, Context, Task> onRetryAsync)

public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, int retryCount, Func<int, Context, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider, Action<Exception, TimeSpan, int, Context> onRetry)

public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, int retryCount,
    Func<int, Context, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider, Func<Exception, TimeSpan, int, Context, Task> onRetryAsync)

public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, int retryCount,
    Func<int, Exception, Context, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider, Func<Exception, TimeSpan, int, Context, Task> onRetryAsync)

public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, IEnumerable<TimeSpan> sleepDurations)

public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, IEnumerable<TimeSpan> sleepDurations, Action<Exception, TimeSpan> onRetry)

public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, IEnumerable<TimeSpan> sleepDurations, Func<Exception, TimeSpan, Task> onRetryAsync)

public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, IEnumerable<TimeSpan> sleepDurations, Action<Exception, TimeSpan, Context> onRetry)

public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, IEnumerable<TimeSpan> sleepDurations, Func<Exception, TimeSpan, Context, Task> onRetryAsync)

public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, IEnumerable<TimeSpan> sleepDurations, Action<Exception, TimeSpan, int, Context> onRetry)

public static AsyncRetryPolicy WaitAndRetryAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, IEnumerable<TimeSpan> sleepDurations, Func<Exception, TimeSpan, int, Context, Task> onRetryAsync)
```

It is pretty easy to got lost. Even for those who were using this API quite frequently.

Another big problem with this: it is also not extensibility friendly. Let me show you an example:

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .RetryAsync(3, onRetry: (exception, retryCount, context) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    });
```

Let's extend this with a new clause to trigger for negative numbers as well

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .OrResult<int>(Int32.IsNegative)
    .RetryAsync(3, onRetry: (exception, retryCount, context) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    });
```

This code won't compile **anymore** with the following error (pointing to the `exception.Message`):

> `DelegateResult<int>` does not contain a definition for `Message` and no accessible extension method `Message` accepting a first argument of type `DelegateResult<int>` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

So, what happened? The first version of the policy triggers **only** if an exception occurred. So, the first parameter of the `onRetry` was indeed an `Exception`.

The second version of the policy triggers either if an exception occurred or a negative number is returned. So, the first parameter of the `onRetry` now is `DelegateResult<int>` and not an `Exception` **anymore**.

The `DelegateResult` does not have a `Message` property rather a `Result` and an `Exception`. That's why we have the compilation error.

---

All in all it takes some time to get familiar with the V7 API and its design decisions. V8 is a complete rewrite which tried to address all of these problems.